# How can I create my own widgets in WordPress?

Tags: widgets

```
function wp_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'wp_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wp_load_widget' );

class wp_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct( 'wp_widget', __('WPBeginner Widget', 'wp_widget_domain'), array( 'description' => __( 'Sample widget based on WPBeginner Tutorial', 'wp_widget_domain' ), ) 
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> These below links will help you for creating own widgets in WordPress with step by step.

- https://kinsta.com/blog/create-wordpress-widget/
- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/create-custom-wordpress-widget/
- https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-widget-in-wordpress
- https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/